# Is there an event for when a UIImage has finished loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am displaying a UIImage view with this code:

```
NSURL *imageUrl = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://..."];
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
UIImage *audioArt =[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
UIImageView *artView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:audioArt];

artView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
artView.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
artView.frame = viewRef.bounds;
[artView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
[artView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[viewRef setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[viewRef addSubview:artView];
```

Is there an event in Objective C to tell when this UIImage has finished loading or when the UIImageView has finished displaying the image?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your `.h`

```
@interface YourClass : YourSuperclass<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableData *imageData;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger totalBytes;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger receivedBytes;
```

And somewhere call

```
NSURL *imageUrl = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://..."];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: imageUrl];
NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

And also implement the delegate methods

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) urlResponse;
    NSDictionary *dict = httpResponse.allHeaderFields;
    NSString *lengthString = [dict valueForKey:@"Content-Length"];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSNumber *length = [formatter numberFromString:lengthString];
    self.totalBytes = length.unsignedIntegerValue;

    [self.imageData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:self.totalBytes];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.imageData appendData:data];
    self.receivedBytes += data.length;

    // Actual progress is self.receivedBytes / self.totalBytes
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.imageData];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //handle error
}
```

**Update:**

Since `NSMutableData initWithLength:` creates a data object whose raw data is filled with zeros, replace `initWithLength:` with just `init` and it will works.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have logged the whole process, and I am definitely receiving data. However at the end of it all `imageView.image=(null)` - can you think of any reason for this?

Comment: Have you allocated your imageView?

Comment: Yeah the image view is allocated, when I NSLog `self.imageData` when the connection has finished loading, the data starts with loads of zero's (like a couple of Kbs of zero's) - Ive tried doing something like `if(data!=nil){[self.imageData appendData:data]}` but that isnt working. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: `NSMutableData initWithLength:` creates a data object whose raw data is filled with zeros

Comment: ah, ive replaced `initWithLength:` with just `init` and it works great! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`UIImage` doesn't have any delegate or callback which tells you about its successful loading.

If you are getting the image from any url, you can use `NSURL`'s delegates and notifications to track if you received the image or not.

Also you can achieve it as :

```
- (void)loadImage:(NSString *)filePath {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImageInBackground:) withObject:filePath];
}

- (void)loadImageInBackground:(NSString *)filePath {
   @autoreleasepool{
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(didLoadImageInBackground:) withObject:image waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}

- (void)didLoadImageInBackground:(UIImage *)image {
    self.imageView.image = image;
}
```

Comment: The OP is a bit unclear about what he understands about "loading". But this "notification" will not be scheduled at the point in time when the image is "loaded". Where "loaded" means when the image has loaded its data, encoded the data, and UIKit has finally rendered it. An UIImage *lazily* "loads" images. `initWithContentsOfFile:` might only set the file path internally - and that was it.